# Catch-all route with IRouteConstraint in ASP.Net Core 3

Tags: .net-core, routes, constraints, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm using .Net Core MVC 3.0 which defaults to `Endpoint Routing`

The default route config is:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Link}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
        });
```

That will allow me to do CRUD operations on my "Links"
*e.g. /Link/Edit/123*

What I need to be able to do is catch and route any request which is NOT a CRUD operation to another controller and action
*e.g. /blahblah*
So that I can process them as I like (probably a redirect, maybe just a friendly notice, could be anything!)

Back in my .Net Framework MVC, one would add a route config like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "MyCatchAll",
            url: "{key}",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction" },
            constraints: new { key = new MyConstraint() }
        );
```

(the purpose of the constraint is simply an optional check that I might need to use for example, to ensure that `blahblah` matches an expected value)

However, I cannot get this to work in .Net Core MVC 3.0

Any pointers would be most appreciated.

Comment: How would you separate any CRUD route from non-CRUD theoretically? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @MuhammadHannan: my .net framework example code in the post is how I used to achieve the same in .net framework, but .net core 3 uses endpoint routing by default (which is what I'm trying to understand better) which is configured differently

Answer (score 1):

For asp.net core 3.0, you could use below configuration:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "MyCatchAll",
        pattern: "{key}",
        defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction" },
        constraints: new { key = new MyConstraint() }
    );
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

MyConstraint.cs

```
public class MyConstraint: IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext,
                        IRouter router,
                        string parameterName,
                        RouteValueDictionary values,
                        RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var url = values["key"];
        //your logic to check
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this on my first attempt but my constraint code breakpoint wasnt even being hit whilst I was receiving a 404 for requests like `/blahblah` implying that the route `MyCatchAll` wasnt being matched for some reason. I believe it has something to do with route specificity priority (the more specific a route map is, the higher its priority -- apparently regardless of how wildly inaccurate or non-matching it might be in any given situation, LOL!)